# How to generate all permutations of a list but also add strings that can be present only once in any permutation

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

`itertools.product` is very convenient to generate all permutations of a list, but how would one proceed to implicate another list of elements where only one element of that list could populate any permutation at a time ?

In pseudocode :

```
from itertools import product
product('ABC', repeat=1) + ['.', '%3A']
->A, B, C, .A, .B, .C, A., B., C., %3AA, %3AB, %3AC, A%3A, B%3A, C%3A
```

I suppose it would be non trivial and one would have to tweak the permutation building algorithm.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to ask about your problem instead of asking how to implement a solution you devised (see [The X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 series. The original input string as a list, and then you prepend and append. Generate those three separately:

```
from itertools import chain, product

inputstring = 'ABC'
extra = ['.', '%3A']
for combo in chain(inputstring, 
        product(extra, inputstring), product(inputstring, extra)):
    combo = ''.join(combo)
    print(combo)
```

Demo with a list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, product
>>> inputstring = 'ABC'
>>> extra = ['.', '%3A']
>>> [''.join(combo) for combo in chain(inputstring, product(extra, inputstring), product(inputstring, extra))]
['A', 'B', 'C', '.A', '.B', '.C', '%3AA', '%3AB', '%3AC', 'A.', 'A%3A', 'B.', 'B%3A', 'C.', 'C%3A']
```

Comment: what if in my pseudocode I increase the `repeat` argument, I would need the extra strings to get inside the string, ig `A.A, A%3AA, ..`

Comment: @ChiseledAbs: please don't move the goalposts. Putting values *inside* is another iteration of the `product`; wrap a `product(inputstring, extra)` in a generator (expression or function) that doubles up the extra letter (`combo + (combo[0],)`.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs: as Paulo points out in a comment on your question, you need to be clearer as to what problem you are solving; it helps in giving you a clear solution to that problem, not just how to implement what you think is the solution. That way we don't end up finding more and more variations you didn't yet think of in the commonts.